# Why is Carrierwave-Backgrounder / Sidekiq triggering redundant image processing?

Tags: carrierwave, sidekiq

I'm using Carrierwave-Backgrounder with Sidekiq to process User icons. Unfortunately, every time I update the User model it triggers CarrierWave::Workers::ProcessAsset to process the existing image. Is there a way to make the backgrounder run only if the User has an icon or changes an existing one? I've tried everything...

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  mount_uploader :icon, IconUploader
  process_in_background :icon
```

**icon_uploader.rb**

```
class IconUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
```

> INFO: Booting Sidekiq 2.14.1 using redis://localhost:6379/0 with options 
> INFO: Running in ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) 
> INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
>
> CarrierWave::Workers::ProcessAsset JID-f2c19a1e33e83be2dce31961 INFO: start
> CarrierWave::Workers::ProcessAsset JID-f2c19a1e33e83be2dce31961 INFO: done: 0.733 sec
> CarrierWave::Workers::ProcessAsset JID-a497e66f54609f76678db81a INFO: start
> CarrierWave::Workers::ProcessAsset JID-a497e66f54609f76678db81a INFO: done: 0.32 sec
> CarrierWave::Workers::ProcessAsset JID-576dd9a036323e700e86860c INFO: start
> CarrierWave::Workers::ProcessAsset JID-576dd9a036323e700e86860c INFO: done: 0.588 sec

Comment: There might be something in your `User` model which is "dirtying" the `icon` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

As gems go, carrierwave-backgrounder is pretty simple. They only enqueue a job if the field has been "updated", where "[updated](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder/blob/master/lib/backgrounder/orm/activemodel.rb#L18)" is defined as any of the following being true:

1. avatar_changed?
2. previous_changes.has_key?(:avatar)
3. remote_avatar_url.present?
4. avatar_cache.present?

1 & 2 apply if you're changing the avatar through assignment, 3 applies if you're letting people paste in URLs, and 4 applies if you're caching changes between form reloads.

If you're absolutely certain that none of those are the case and you're still seeing jobs on every save, you may want to create an issue on their issue tracker.

Comment: I'm getting this all the time, it IS very straightforward to set up. However I'm still seing Redis throw a ton of errors if I edit a record that already has an icon, modify a completely different attribute, and then save. I can't believe I'm the only one noticing this. Must be something simple I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's totally possible there could be a bug. If you can come up with simple instructions to replicate the problem I'm sure the maintainers would be happy for the report.